# underscorejs - how to loop a object and call the function from the object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a object with Boolean value, once the value is true, i would like to test the same value is there in my object as function, if there, then i would like to call that function. I can do this by just using javascript.

But I am looking some good way using underscorejs.. is possible?

here is my try:

```
var requiredViews : {
  "breadCrumbView": false,
  "headerView": false,
  "footerView": false
}
var that = this;
_.each(requiredViews , function(val,key){
   if(val && _.contaions(_.functions(that, key))){
  that[key]();
 }
})
```

apart from is there any shortcut way to pick the true value key alone from object and call that?

any one suggest me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`functions`](http://underscorejs.org/#object-functions) method only takes one argument. It seems like you're looking for something like this:

```
_.each(requiredViews , function(val,key){
    if(val && _.contains(_.functions(that), key)) {
        that[key]();
    }
})
```

Also, calling `_.functions` on every iteration seems wasteful, you might want to cache it like this:

```
var funcs = _.functions(that);
_.each(requiredViews , function(val,key){
    if(val && _.contains(funcs, key)) {
        that[key]();
    }
})
```

Or perhaps use [`isFunction`](http://underscorejs.org/#isFunction) instead:

```
_.each(requiredViews , function(val,key){
    if(val) {
        var func = that[key];
        if (_.isFunction(func)) {
            func();
        }
    }
})
```